# Liferay search content for a specific groupid

Tags: search, liferay

I would like to ask, how can I search web-content of my site for a specific group-id.
Now I have a method which searches correctly by `keyword` in all of the web-content but doesn't search for a specific group-id.

Any ideas?

```java
HttpServletRequest httpReq = FacesService.getHttpServletRequest();
//PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest() );
//(PortletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest()

SearchContext searchContext = SearchContextFactory.getInstance(httpReq );

searchContext.setKeywords(query);
searchContext.setEnd(2000);
searchContext.setStart(0);

String[] entryCalssName = {JournalArticle.class.getName()};

searchContext.setEntryClassNames(entryCalssName);
searchContext.setAttribute(Field.GROUP_ID, 14603);

Facet assetEntriesFacet = new AssetEntriesFacet(searchContext);

assetEntriesFacet.setStatic(true);

searchContext.addFacet(assetEntriesFacet);

Facet scopeFacet = new ScopeFacet(searchContext);

scopeFacet.setStatic(true);

searchContext.addFacet(scopeFacet);

Indexer indexer = FacetedSearcher.getInstance();

Hits hits = indexer.search(searchContext);

List<JournalArticle>   searchResults = new ArrayList<JournalArticle>();

documents = hits.toList();

if (documents != null && !documents.isEmpty()) {
    for(Document doc : documents) {

        Long classPK = Long.parseLong(doc.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK));

        AssetEntry assetEntry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntry(JournalArticle.class.getName(), classPK);

        JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(assetEntry.getClassPK()); 

        System.out.println(article.getGroupId());

        // if(article.getGroupId() == groupId){//I would like to get rid of this

        searchResults.add(article);

        // }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way to set groupId in `SearchContext`?

```java
searchContext.setGroupIds(long[] groupIds);
```